# Targeting hosts in a group in order with Ansible

Tags: ansible

In [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) it is suggested that it is possible when using Ansible to target hosts in a group in order. For example the documentation uses a group `webservers`

```
[webservers]
cobweb
webbing
weber
```

The documentation then suggests that using `webservers[0]` would to target `cobweb`. In my environment I have two nodes in a group and targeting the first node using `[0]` will return the second and not the first node in the group.

Ansible runs in AWX and the inventory project is based on Git source. AWX also lists the group in correct order in the web interface but when I output the group it is in reverse order.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "hosts: {{ groups['my_group'] }}"
```

Is this is a known issue? The results I am getting I think suggest that the order is randomized. So the documentation is incorrect or there is a bug in Ansible or AWX.

I am using Ansible 2.9.17 with AWX 17.0.1.

The way the `groups` vars is sorted is IMHO independent of order strategy. So for example when I have a play as shown below I can tell Ansible to use inventory order.

```yaml
  hosts: my_group
  order: inventory
  roles: ...
```

This is has no relation to order of list `groups['my_group']` as far I can tell.

Comment: There were some bugs in 2.9.x version if I recon properly, yes. Also see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory, where you can act on the order versus https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory, the same page for this version, which doesn't point at ordering

Comment: Regarding your observation and question "_Is this is a known issue?_" I like to confirm that I made the same observation in my environment. Whereby via an Ansilble CLI command like `ansible-playbook` the order is from "top to down", executing the same script via Ansible Tower changes the order to "bottom up".

Comment: You might want to check you are not using different [order strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory) in each case.

Comment: @Zeitounator the groups var is input for the order strategy, you cannot apply an order strategy against it.

Comment: Running `delegate_to: {{ groups['mygroup'][0] }}` and `- hosts: mygroup[0]` works fine. (Ansible 2.9.17).  

I don't quite get the: _In my environment I have two nodes in a group and targeting the first node using [0] will return the second and not the first node in the group._ Like child?